# Copying and pasting specific file types in folders and subfolders

Tags: bash

I have a top level folder which contains many subfolders. I am trying to copy the mp4 files from inside those subfolders to a single directory. From the small amount of knowledge I have from codecademy, this command is the closest I could come to the desire function.

```
cp /masterDir/*.mp4 /outputFolder
```

but this would only copy any mp4 files found in the top directory.

In short, is there any concise way to tell the command line I want it to go through all the subfolders and copy any that meet the file type? Is this a case for a python "for each" script?

Answer (score 1):

**`find`** + **`cp`** solution:

```
find /masterdir -type f -name "*.mp4" -exec cp -t /outputFolder {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` and execute `cp` for the results

```
$ find /masterDir -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec cp {} /outputFolder \;
```

Explanation:

`-type f` - Find files

`-name '*.mp4'` - All files ending with .mp4

`-exec` - Execute cp command within the results